# difference between unit testing a web project and a silverlight project (How to unit test a silverlight project)

Tags: unit-testing, silverlight-4.0, project

I know unit testing but haven't done unit testing for silverlight project yet. Can anyone let me know how to unit test a silverlight project. Is the approach different than unit testing a asp.net project?

Any resource/tutorial regarding this would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To unit test a Silverlight app, you can use the Silverlight unit testing framework available in the [Silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the response ... I was bit confused about how to start unit testing a silverlight project. I mean is the approach same as unit testing web project or we need to do anything special?

Comment: It is special because it's UI oriented